# insert in two table with join such that id of one table is to insert in another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables booking and client. Booking table will have client's id. Now I want to ask for booking detail first and then user detail next. The problem for me is when I insert booking detail first then insert user detail next I have to insert user's id in booking table. how is it possible?

note:i have to do in core php.

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: what you have already tried far?